# Reset list's paging when select value from dropdown menu sencha touch 2.1

Tags: list, drop-down-menu, paging, reset, sencha-touch-2.1

I need to dynamic populate list by select value from dropdownlist.

For example when I select **Active** record then my list will populate record which are **active**.And if I select **Delete** record then list will populate record which are **delete**.

Please see my code below

Model.js

```
  Ext.define('bluebutton.model.BlueButton.TransactionList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        idProperty:'transactionId',
//         id:'transactionlistmodel',

        fields: [
            {  name: "transactionId" ,type:"string" },
            {  name: "merchant_bbID" ,type:"string" },
            {  name: "sessionId"  ,type:"string"},
            {  name: "deviceId"  ,type:"string"},
            {  name: "createDateTime" ,type:"string"},
            {  name: "fullName" ,type:"string"},
            {  name: "action" ,type:"string"},
            {  name: "updatedPoint" ,type:"string"},
            {  name: "createDate" ,type:"string"},
            {  name: "status",type:"string" },


        ],



        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',

           url: 'http://localhost:8080/WebCommon/rest/BBWebService/getPointTransactionList',
//            url: 'http://mixsoloffice.no-ip.biz:82/WebCommon/rest/BBWebService/getPointTransactionList',
            actionMethods: {
                create: 'POST',
                read: 'GET',
                update: 'PUT',
                destroy: 'DELETE'
            },


//                      noCache: false, // get rid of the '_dc' url parameter

                    extraParams: {
                        sessionId: "1",
                        deviceId: "1",
                        merchant_bbID: "merchant1",
                        filterType :"0"

                    // add as many as you need
                },



            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'pointTransHistoryList',
                 totalProperty: 'totalRecord',
                 successProperty: 'success',


            },

            writer: {
                type: 'json',

            },
        }



    }

});
```

Store.js

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.store.BlueButton.TransactionList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
       requires: [
              'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.TransactionList'
    ],

    config: {
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function (record) {
                return record.get('createDateTime');
            }


        },



            model: 'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.TransactionList',
            pageSize: 5,
             autoLoad: true,
            storeId: 'transactionliststore',
            sorters: 'createDateTime',
            groupDir: 'DESC',
             autoSync: true,
            clearOnPageLoad: false, 



    }
});
```

view.js

```
    Ext.define('bluebutton.view.BlueButton.TransactionList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'transactionlistcard',

    requires: [
        'Ext.field.Select',
        'Ext.field.Search',

        'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
        'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',

        'bluebutton.store.BlueButton.TransactionList',

    ],
    config: {



        styleHtmlContent: true,
               scrollable: {
            direction: 'vertical',
            directionLock: true
        },

        singleSelect: true,

        grouped: true,
        variableHeights : false,
           store : { xclass : 'bluebutton.store.BlueButton.TransactionList'},
            itemHeight :100,
        loadingText : 'loading',
        id :'transactionlist',


            masked: {
                xtype: 'loadmask',
                message: 'loading...'
            }, // masked
       plugins: [

                        {

                            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
                             pullRefreshText: 'Pull down for more new Tweets!',         

//                                      refreshFn: function(callback, plugin) {
//                                                 var store = plugin.list.getStore();
//                                            store.load(function(records, operation, success) {
//                                                callback.call(plugin);
//                                                console.log( records );
//                                     });

//                                 }


                        },


                        { 
                            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
//                               


                        }
                ],



        emptyText: '<p class="no-search-results">No Transaction record found matching that search</p>',
        itemTpl: Ext.create(
           'Ext.XTemplate',
            '<div class="tweet-wrapper">',
                '<table>',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td rowspan="2" width="28%" >',
//                        '<div style="padding-left: 30px;">',
//                        '   <img src="{imgUrl}" width="140" height="130" /></div>',
                        '</td>',
                        '<td>',
                        '   <div class="tweet">',

                        '       <h3>Transaction ID: {transactionId} , Point: {updatedPoint} pts , Action: {action}</h3>',
                        '       <h3>Status: {status}, Transaction By: {fullName} , Transaction Date: {createDateTime}</h3>',

                        '   </div>',
                        '</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                '</table>',
            '</div>'



        ),


         listeners: {
            updatedata: function (me, newData, eOpts ) {
                alert(newData)
            }
        },

    },



});
```

Controller.js

```
 onTransactionStatusChange:  function (selectField, value) {


                var sto = Ext.getCmp('transactionlist').getStore();

                sto.removeAll();
                sto.sync()





             var thelist = this.getTransactionlist();
              thelist.setStore(sto);


                sto.load({
                    params:{
                        filterType : value,
                        sessionId :'1',
                        merchant_bbID:'merchant1',
                        page:'1',
                        start:'0',
                        limit:'5'

                    }


            });





    },
```

Now I facing a problem.

Let say In **active**  list , current page is page 2 and  it displaying **no more record loaded**  .  But when I change to **delete** list, the list also displaying **no more record loaded** . How can I reset the paging when I select value from my dropdown list